# SriVaishnava - propitiation rituals for the Pitrs - redemption for breaks

Tags: scripture, rituals, sri-vaishnava, pitru

What happens if there is a break in the propitiation of [Pitrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitrs)(ancestors) in patrilineal lineage? Are subsequent generations affected adversely? How so?

Supposing there is a minimum of one generation gap in the performance of these rituals, what are the [Prāyaścitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C4%81ya%C5%9Bcitta) to be pursued to redeem the situation permanently?

**Answers that draw reference wholly applicable to SriVaishnava Sampradaya are requested. Please quote scriptures as much as possible.**

Comment: I think everyone is affected by break in the propitiation of Ancestors aka Pitra Dosha. There is no prayaschitta afaik,  sharanagati would take care of everything else but one should get upanayana and then do the tarpana etc.

Comment: If one is a prapannan there is nothing other than the Lord's Mercy as one's path. However, to honor the pitrs, and in a mood of service to the Supreme Being, my Acharya instructs us to perform tharpanam as an obligation to our deha Sambandhis.